# How to look up a list of variables by their names

Tags: ansible

Given a list of variable names, I want to look them up and return a list of their values.

Writing such a list manually is tedious and somewhat less readable:

```yaml
my_list:
- "{{ foo }}"
- "{{ bar }}"
# ...
```

It's possible to write it with just one pair of `{{ }}`, but then it results in a potentially very long, single-line expression.

```yaml
mylist: "{{ [foo, bar, ...] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [vars lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html):

```
{{ query('vars', *my_list) }}
```

The `*` is the trickiest part of this Jinja expression, because it’s a Pythonism. It takes the list and unpacks it into positional arguments. If you leave off the `*` you’re passing in the list as a single argument, and the vars lookup doesn’t expect a list so it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This expression worked quite well for me:

```yaml
vars:
  my_list: "{{ variable_names|map('extract', vars)|map('mandatory') }}"
  variable_names:
  - foo
  - bar
  # ...
```

The trick is to use [`extract`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) to look up names in the special variable `vars` (which I couldn't find officially documented anywhere - I'll be happy to learn).

Using `map('mandatory')` ensures that Ansible won't silently skip missing variables (if so desired).

---

Yet another alternative is to use [YAML multi-line strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/1333025) to split a list to multiple lines:

```yaml
my_list: >-
  {{ [
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  ] }}
```

Comment: `vars` is an undocumented internal variable with some surprising behaviour and should not be used. The only reason it is only still present because there's not yet a clean deprecation path for removing it. The `vars` lookup is the supported method of retrieving vars.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to express the solution without using `vars`?